# Unable to use String received from InputStream?

Tags: swift

I am reading a String from an input stream but when I put it in a switch statement, it never matches anything. I did some investigation and I found out that the length of the string is 4096 bytes instead of 23 (what its supposed to be). 4096 is also the buffer, which might be the reason why. I'd appreciate any help as this has stumped me for the past couple hours :(
Here is the code in question:

http://pastebin.com/ytZhwxRy

Comment: Please put the actual relevant code in your question, not as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `NSString`, use `len` for the count instead of `buffer.count`. Unlike a C `char` pointer, an `NSString` can contain `'\x0'` bytes, so you have to tell it the exact size of the data you're providing it.